# Why would a WPF Button not always fire its bound Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, prism

I have a user control which is part of an app that is composed using Prism. It has this 'Back' Button:

```
<Button Content="Back"
        Command="{Binding BackCommand}"
        Padding="5 12 5 2" />
```

Sometimes this button doesn't execute the command. The view model provides this command:

```
public class BackCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IInterviewController _controller;

    public BackCommand(IInterviewController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _controller.MovePreviousTopic();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

In addition the user control has a 'Next' button that moves the user though the a series of branching questions based on what the user selects in a second control. The back button is supposed to take the user to the previous question. The back button usually executes the bound command so I know the binding works. Sometimes the user has to click the back button twice before the command will fire. I replaced the CanExecute body to always return true (as shown above) still the button stops working.

I put temporary event handlers on the button and discovered that when the command fails to execute:

- the button is enabled
- the binding is still set
- the PreviewMouseDown event on the button fires
- the Click event does not fire (even if I remove the command)
- the command's Execute method is not called.

Every question on SO I'm finding about commands not firing, the OP was having one issue or another binding the command. Since my command is bound, I'm not finding much useful.

Edit #2: I have discovered the cause of the issue. One of the components composed into the application is trying to control focus. To reproduce the issue, paste this into a window:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Current count:"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Counter}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding MaintainFocus}" LostFocus="MaintainFocus" >Maintain Focus</CheckBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Content="Test" Width="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

Paste this into the window's code behind:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ViewModel _vm;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = _vm = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MaintainFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_vm.MaintainFocus)
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                new Action(() => MyCheckbox.Focus()));
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new TestCommand(this);
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    private int _counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get { return _counter; }
        set
        {
            _counter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool MaintainFocus { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public TestCommand(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.Counter++;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Now, if you check the Maintain Focus checkbox, the Test button will not fire.

Comment: Maybe when your button doesn't fire Click event you click on the empty space inside the button? Try set `Background="#00000000"` on the border inside button's ControlTemplate. I'm sure it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix for my issue is to not allow the Button to take focus:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        Focusable="False"
        Content="Test"
        Width="100" />
```

It seems to be a problem for WPF's ICommand if the button looses focus before the command executes but not if the button never gets focus in the first place.

I was fortunate that the functionality for these buttons has been provided though Tab Navigation on the control so I didn't need to refactor the code setting focus. Since the UI designer doesn't want to show keyboard focus on the button, this is a Win-Win in my book.

One of the initial questions I had was how to debug this problem. I never got a suitable answer for this, so I'll summarize my process below:

1. Don't use break points  - these interfere with debugging mouse interactions.
2. Add `Debug.WriteLine("<something meaningful>");` to each event/method that is invoked as a result of the mouse click. This told me what what events were working, which ones weren't and the order. It didn't really help.
3. Because this was a result of resent changes, I commented out the recent changes, 1 by 1, until I identified the code causing the issue. This ended up being a call into the component causing the issue.
4. Once I identified the problematic line of code in my changes, I uncommitted that line and stepped through that call. This led me to the code setting focus using the Dispatcher.
5. This line was highly suspect, so I built a sample project that mimicked the code and verified that the source of the problem was here.

Maybe this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Hi, I'm from the future and this was helpful.  I had a button in two datagrids and the command binding was not firing unless I clicked the button twice or it already had focus.  Adding Focusable=False resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the `Image` should raise the `Click` event. If you however set the `Padding` property and click outside of the actual `Image`, the `Click` event won't be raised.

You could fix this by putting the `Border` element inside a `Grid` with a `Transparent` background:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
                        <Image Name="Image"
                               Source="{Binding NormalImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Image"
                                Property="Source"
                                Value="{Binding PressedImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But please note that you should always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when you ask a question.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the background has no effect on the button's behavior. It still fails to execute the command in a specific case even though the command can execute

Comment: I guess you should read the last sentence in my answer again.

Comment: I'm still working on isolating the code responsible for the problem. Currently the minimal code required to reproduce this is the entire application, and I can't post that on the Internet. This is the reason for the question: "Does anyone have any idea why the button would not respond to being clicked or how to even troubleshoot this?" at he end of rthe original post

Comment: The minimal reproducible solution has been posted for a while now

Comment: "One of the components composed into the application is trying to control focus". So why don't you remove this component? It's clearly not working, right? The sample code you have posted doesn't make much sense. As soon as the Checkbox loses focus, you focus it again which will of course prevent the clicked Button from getting focus.

Comment: Well it certainly is part of the problem, but it does provide a lot of functionality that works correctly. Some debugging shows that the checkbox looses focus, the button gets focus, then the checkbox takes focus back. I'm going to report the issue to Microsoft and maybe WPF will be patched in the future. 

I agree, the minimal reproduction of the issue is nonsense. It has the essence but not the character of the component. The actual code is more complicated, involving dynamically added controls. Maybe the original dev knew what edge case this was meant to handle and it made sense to him?